# Display a QFileSystemModel in two Views: Tree View and a TableView/ListView of selected items

Tags: qt, qml

I have a model derived from `QFileSystemModel`. I extended it by a Role which holds a bool value which indicates whether a file has been selected for later use. This model is displayed in a `qml` `TreeView`. In this view I can select files via checkboxes. I have a list of `QPersistentModelIndex` of the selected indices stored in my model.

In a different view (probably a `ListView` or `TableView`), I would like to display only items, which have have been selected in the `TreeView`. In this other view I also want to be able to remove the selection. So the question is whether this can be done with only one model (or maybe a QSortFilterProxyModel inbetween) or whether I need to have two models communicating with each other.

Comment: You can filter items based on any role. You need to override `QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow()` function and set filter role to be your custom role with `setFilterRole()` function.

Comment: I edited the question according to your suggestion

Comment: Did you try to set `setFilterRole(FileSystemModel::BoolRole)` to your proxy model?

Comment: No, but even when I try the result is the same. Actually, also when I try to do a QIdentityProxyModel without anything, I get nothing shown.

Comment: when you do `FileListModel { id: fileListModel }` in QML, you are creating a new `FileListModel`, not using the one you called `setContextProperty` with.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was indeed my problem. I edited the question to the problem which arises now

Comment: @maxwell If an item has children, should the children be shown? Can the directories be selected or only the files?

Comment: only files can be selected, and files on different levels of the directory tree should all appear without hirarchy in the list